# Backup/Restore failed for SQL Server exception smo.extended C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, smo

```
public static readonly string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=JOSEPH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Storage;Integrated Security=True";

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtrestore.Text) | string.IsNullOrEmpty(ComboBoxserverName.Text) | string.IsNullOrEmpty(ComboBoxDatabaseName.Text))
        {
            // label3.Visible = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Server Name & Database & Restore file can not be Blank");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            , ComboBoxDatabaseName.Text, ComboBoxserverName.Text);
            RestoreDatabase(ComboBoxDatabaseName.Text, "C:\RESTORE\hw.bak", ComboBoxserverName.Text);
            label4.Visible = true;
            label4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            label4.Text = "Database restore has been created successfully";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void Backup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ComboBoxserverName.Text) | string.IsNullOrEmpty(ComboBoxDatabaseName.Text))
       {
           // label3.Visible = true;
           MessageBox.Show("Server Name & Database can not be Blank");
           return;
       }
       else {
           SaveFileDialog1.FileName = ComboBoxDatabaseName.Text;
           SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
           string s = null;
           s = SaveFileDialog1.FileName;
           BackupDatabase(s + ".bak", ComboBoxDatabaseName.Text, ComboBoxserverName.Text);
           label3.Visible = true;
           label3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
           label3.Text = "Database backup has been created successfully";
       }
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}

backup</param>

public void BackupDatabase(string backUpFile,string db,string srv)
{
    try {
        ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(@""+srv);
        Server server = new Server(con);
        Backup source = new Backup();
        source.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
        source.Database = db;
        BackupDeviceItem destination = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpFile, DeviceType.File);
        source.Devices.Add(destination);
        source.SqlBackup(server);
        con.Disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

public void RestoreDatabase(String databaseName, String backUpFile, String srv)
{
     Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server smoServer = new Server(new ServerConnection(srv));

     Database db = smoServer.Databases["Storage"];

     string dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(db.PrimaryFilePath, "Storage.MDF");
     string logPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(db.PrimaryFilePath, "Storage_1.LDF");

     Restore restore = new Restore();
     BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem("C:/RESTORE/hw.BAK", DeviceType.File);
     restore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
     restore.Database = "C:/RESTORE/hw.BAK";

     string fileMdf = System.IO.Path.Combine(smoServer.MasterDBPath, "Storage.mdf");
     string fileLdf = System.IO.Path.Combine(smoServer.MasterDBLogPath, "Storage_1.ldf");

     RelocateFile relocateMdf = new RelocateFile("Storage", fileMdf);
     RelocateFile relocateLdf = new RelocateFile("Storage_1", fileLdf);

     restore.RelocateFiles.Add(relocateMdf);
     restore.RelocateFiles.Add(relocateLdf);
     restore.FileNumber = 1;
     restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
     restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
     restore.SqlRestore(smoServer);

     db = smoServer.Databases["Storage"];
     db.SetOnline();
     smoServer.Refresh();
     db.Refresh();
}
```

Ok that's my code. By the way I know I dont use the params in restore method but this is one of many ways I tried to implement this method.

I get from both methods the same error

> Backup failed for server JOSEPH-PC/SQLEXPRESS

or

> Restore failed for server JOSEPH-PC/SQLEXPRESS.

Backup was working yesterday and restore didn't.

Now none of these methods are working and I didn't change a thing in code for BACKUP.

I also have tried these two commands

```
  private string singleUserCmd = "alter database Storage set SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";
        private string multiUserCmd = "alter database Storage set MULTI_USER";
```

same error again...

I have spent over 10 hrs searching posts , I have tried many ways to implement these methods, i would appreciate an answer to this.

Thank you.

Comment: Tag dbms used. Product specific issue!

Comment: Can you please grab the inner exception that is causing the jobs to fail? That will likely reveal the root cause of the failures.

Comment: an exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch thats the innerexception.

Comment: Backup works now. Restore still doesnt.

Comment: What did you change to get backup working? You need to dig down into those exceptions to get to the problem. Somewhere along the way, you'll find a concrete problem. Make sure that you're looking down into the full stack trace for all the exceptions and their inner exceptions.

Comment: actually i didnt change any code , i did change the pc the database was running.